# Pinching touchpad enlarges/magnifies website instead of changing zoom level

Tags: windows-10, firefox, touchpad, zoom

When I try to pinch zoom website in Firefox, instead of changing zoom level (like enlarging text but modifying layout so it still fits screen) it enlarges parts of website, adding horizontal scrollbar.

[image: Pinching enlarges part of screen]

If I hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> when pinching using touchpad (or use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll wheel), it then  changes page zoom and updates zoom value (110%, 120%...).

[image: Pinching while holding ctrl changes zoom level]

Is there a way to change touchpad behaviour so I can change zoom level by pinching without holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>? OS is Windows 10. Additionally, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + pinch method doesn't work in Edge - still only magnifies part of website.

Comment: In `about:config` there is option `browser.gesture.pinch.in` that by default contains `cmd_fullZoomReduce`. If you'll find alternative command corresponding to scale change you could replace it.